# Comparing factor analyses from different surveys

Tags: survey, analysis, meta-analysis

I am trying to replicate a study that used factor analysis on a survey to identify latent constructs. So I administered a similar survey and also performed a factor analysis. How do I compare the results of these two analyses?  Or, can someone provide an example of how this is done in the literature? Thank you!

Comment: It seems Confirmatory Factor Analysis is used in this situation, but now I need to understand what that is